# Angular Material FAB Speed Dial has offset in Toolbar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I tried to adpot some design examples from the angular material site . I use Angular Material 1.0.0RC5.

I want to place the FAB Speedial inside the Toolbar like in their example
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial
[image]

But when I apply the code i see on the page i also got a strange offset which i can only correct with a `margin-top:-23px` but I assume i'm doing something wrong.

[image]

I can also see the offset in the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BogOzd) from the site has the same bug if exceeding some size [image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Below I attach the code of the screen

```
<body ng-app="starterApp" layout="column" ng-controller="AppController as ac" ng-cloak>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>
                <span>Toolbar with Icon Buttons</span>
            </h2>
            <span flex></span>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-fab-speed-dial md-open="isOpen" md-direction="down" class="md-scale md-fab-top-right">
        <md-fab-trigger>
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="menu"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
        <md-fab-actions>
            <md-button aria-label="Twitter" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="android" aria-label="Twitter"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button aria-label="Facebook" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="windows" aria-label="Facebook"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-actions>
    </md-fab-speed-dial>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
            <md-button class="md-accent">Button 1</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-accent">Button 2</md-button>
        </md-sidenav>
        <div layout="column" flex id="content">
            <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
                This Starter Application consists of a Toolbar, SideNav (with two buttons), and Content area.
                <p>This is the content area! </p>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meZGwW)

All I've done is alter the `margin-top` property from 89 to 16 and all works ok now, if I understand what you mean

Comment: So this is expected behavior ? I assumed that this is a "bug" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason theirs works but yours doesn't is because theirs has another element above the menu bar, so they added "margin-top: 89px;" and "top: 16px;" to compensate.

All you need to do is adjust the margin-top value they have set.

```
.fabSpeedDialdemoMoreOptions md-fab-speed-dial {
  margin-top: 65px;
}
```

[See here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbdMJw)